# setOnClickListener of an imageView in a dialog is not working

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, imageview, onclicklistener

I have used the following method on a button click to show a dialog with a image list. The dialog is working okay if I remove setOnclickListener from the images. But the app will stop unfortunately if I used ***setOnclickListener*** to the images.

```
 private void showFrame(){
            frameDialog = new Dialog(CameraActivity.this);
            frameDialog.setContentView(R.layout.frame_selection);
            frameDialog.setTitle("Select a frame");

            ImageView thumb1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.thumbView1);
            ImageView thumb2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.thumbView2);
            ImageView thumb3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.thumbView3);

            frameDialog.show();
            thumb1.setOnClickListener(
                     new View.OnClickListener() {
                         @Override
                         public void onClick(View v) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "to this is okay!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                frameDialog.dismiss();

                         }
                     }
                 );
thumb2.setOnClickListener(
                     new View.OnClickListener() {
                         @Override
                         public void onClick(View v) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "to this is okay!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                frameDialog.dismiss();

                         }
                     }
                 );
                thumb3.setOnClickListener(
                     new View.OnClickListener() {
                         @Override
                         public void onClick(View v) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "to this is okay!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                frameDialog.dismiss();

                         }
                     }
                 );


                }
```

**LogCat**

```
12-13 11:22:07.110: E/AndroidRuntime(17913): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-13 11:22:07.110: E/AndroidRuntime(17913): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-13 11:22:07.110: E/AndroidRuntime(17913):    at com.***.**.**.showFrame(CameraActivity.java:98)
12-13 11:22:07.110: E/AndroidRuntime(17913):    at com.**.**.***.access$0(CameraActivity.java:87)
12-13 11:22:07.110: E/AndroidRuntime(17913):    at com.**.**.**$3.onClick(CameraActivity.java:79)
12-13 11:22:07.110: E/AndroidRuntime(17913):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4261)
12-13 11:22:07.110: E/AndroidRuntime(17913):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17420)
12-13 11:22:07.110: E/AndroidRuntime(17913):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
12-13 11:22:07.110: E/AndroidRuntime(17913):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-13 11:22:07.110: E/AndroidRuntime(17913):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-13 11:22:07.110: E/AndroidRuntime(17913):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4944)
12-13 11:22:07.110: E/AndroidRuntime(17913):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-13 11:22:07.110: E/AndroidRuntime(17913):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-13 11:22:07.110: E/AndroidRuntime(17913):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
12-13 11:22:07.110: E/AndroidRuntime(17913):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
12-13 11:22:07.110: E/AndroidRuntime(17913):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**NB the 98 no line is : *thumb1.setOnClickListener(........*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace

```
 ImageView thumb1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.thumbView1);
 ImageView thumb2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.thumbView2);
 ImageView thumb3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.thumbView3);
```

with

```
 ImageView thumb1 = (ImageView) frameDialog.findViewById(R.id.thumbView1);
 ImageView thumb2 = (ImageView) frameDialog.findViewById(R.id.thumbView2);
 ImageView thumb3 = (ImageView) frameDialog.findViewById(R.id.thumbView3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
ImageView thumb1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.thumbView1);
ImageView thumb2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.thumbView2);
ImageView thumb3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.thumbView3);
```

to

```
ImageView thumb1 = (ImageView)frameDialog.findViewById(R.id.thumbView1);
ImageView thumb2 = (ImageView)frameDialog.findViewById(R.id.thumbView2);
ImageView thumb3 = (ImageView)frameDialog.findViewById(R.id.thumbView3);
```

`findViewById` looks for a view with the id mentioned in the current inflated layout. So you need to use the dialog object to initialize your views.

Comment: Thanks @Raghunandan for your fast response with explain..:)